# Stiff-necked people from Yaakov's neck becoming stiff?

Tags: middos-character-traits, golden-calf-egel, yaakov-and-eisav

Is there any connection between the Jews being called stiff-necked ([Exodus 32.9](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.32.9)) and the encounter of Yaakov and Esav, when the Medresh says Yaakov's neck became stiff ([Bereishis Rabbah 78.9](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.78.9?lang=bi))?

Are there any commentators that point out any associations?

Comment: Note that the Torah says קשה-עורף with regards to the Jews and נעשה-צוארו...שיש with regards to Yaakov, so not as connected as your translation suggests.